# How to change format (e.g. dd/MMM/yyyy) of DateTimePicker in WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I want to Change the Format of date selected in DateTimePicker in WPF Application

Answer (score 15):

I was handling with this issue rencetly. I found a simple way to perform this custom format and I hope that this help you. First thing that you need to do is apply a specific style to your current DatePicker just like this, in your XAML:

```
<DatePicker.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Width="113" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeFormatter},RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}},ConverterParameter=dd-MMM-yyyy}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BaseBorderBrush}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DatePicker.Resources>
```

As you can notice at this part, exist a Converter called DateTimeFormatter at the time to make binding to the Text property of the "PART_TextBox". This converter receives the converterparameter that includes your custom format. Finally we add the code in C# for the DateTimeFormatter converter.

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime? selectedDate = value as DateTime?;

        if (selectedDate != null)
        {
            string dateTimeFormat = parameter as string;
            return selectedDate.Value.ToString(dateTimeFormat);
        }

        return "Select Date";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {

            var valor = value as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valor))
            {
                var retorno = DateTime.Parse(valor);
                return retorno;
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this help to you. Please let me know for any issue or suggesting for improve.

Answer (score 5):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
```

Comment: this is changing in UI control but not in viewmodel property. i am getting same format of computer date format. any idea please?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add this style to your xaml or App.xaml file

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="Control.Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate>
                 <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
            Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy', 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

In XAML:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker SelectedDateFormat="Long" />
```

or

```
<toolkit:DatePicker SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
```

Comment: +1 I wonder if there's a way to provide a custome datetime format string in XAML.

Comment: This property is not available for the DatePickerTextBox control in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Fernando García for the basis of this.

I have written a DateFormat attached property for DatePicker that lets you provide a format string for display and input.

For input it will attempt to parse using the provided format, falling back to trying to parse it with the current culture's format.

Example usage with the question's format:

```
<DatePicker my:DatePickerDateFormat.DateFormat="dd/MMM/yyyy"/>
```

The DateFormat attached property is:

```
public class DatePickerDateFormat
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateFormatProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DateFormat", typeof (string), typeof (DatePickerDateFormat),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(OnDateFormatChanged));

    public static string GetDateFormat(DependencyObject dobj)
    {
        return (string) dobj.GetValue(DateFormatProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDateFormat(DependencyObject dobj, string value)
    {
        dobj.SetValue(DateFormatProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnDateFormatChanged(DependencyObject dobj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var datePicker = (DatePicker) dobj;

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action<DatePicker>(ApplyDateFormat), datePicker);
    }

    private static void ApplyDateFormat(DatePicker datePicker)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("SelectedDate")
            {
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource {AncestorType = typeof (DatePicker)},
                Converter = new DatePickerDateTimeConverter(),
                ConverterParameter = new Tuple<DatePicker, string>(datePicker, GetDateFormat(datePicker))
            };
        var textBox = GetTemplateTextBox(datePicker);
        textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

        textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown;
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown += TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown;

        datePicker.CalendarOpened -= DatePickerOnCalendarOpened;
        datePicker.CalendarOpened += DatePickerOnCalendarOpened;
    }

    private static TextBox GetTemplateTextBox(Control control)
    {
        control.ApplyTemplate();
        return (TextBox) control.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", control);
    }

    private static void TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Return)
            return;

        /* DatePicker subscribes to its TextBox's KeyDown event to set its SelectedDate if Key.Return was
         * pressed. When this happens its text will be the result of its internal date parsing until it
         * loses focus or another date is selected. A workaround is to stop the KeyDown event bubbling up
         * and handling setting the DatePicker.SelectedDate. */

        e.Handled = true;

        var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
        var datePicker = (DatePicker) textBox.TemplatedParent;
        var dateStr = textBox.Text;
        var formatStr = GetDateFormat(datePicker);
        datePicker.SelectedDate = DatePickerDateTimeConverter.StringToDateTime(datePicker, formatStr, dateStr);
    }

    private static void DatePickerOnCalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* When DatePicker's TextBox is not focused and its Calendar is opened by clicking its calendar button
         * its text will be the result of its internal date parsing until its TextBox is focused and another
         * date is selected. A workaround is to set this string when it is opened. */

        var datePicker = (DatePicker) sender;
        var textBox = GetTemplateTextBox(datePicker);
        var formatStr = GetDateFormat(datePicker);
        textBox.Text = DatePickerDateTimeConverter.DateTimeToString(formatStr, datePicker.SelectedDate);
    }

    private class DatePickerDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var formatStr = ((Tuple<DatePicker, string>) parameter).Item2;
            var selectedDate = (DateTime?) value;
            return DateTimeToString(formatStr, selectedDate);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var tupleParam = ((Tuple<DatePicker, string>) parameter);
            var dateStr = (string) value;
            return StringToDateTime(tupleParam.Item1, tupleParam.Item2, dateStr);
        }

        public static string DateTimeToString(string formatStr, DateTime? selectedDate)
        {
            return selectedDate.HasValue ? selectedDate.Value.ToString(formatStr) : null;
        }

        public static DateTime? StringToDateTime(DatePicker datePicker, string formatStr, string dateStr)
        {
            DateTime date;
            var canParse = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, formatStr, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                  DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

            if (!canParse)
                canParse = DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

            return canParse ? date : datePicker.SelectedDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the above mentioned class to get the correct date format. At first sight I thought its working as expected. But after some moments I discovered that when I select a date I get that date in correct format. For e.g. dd.MM.yyyy. Then when I moved focus over other control, I watched that date is again converted to default format i.e. MM.dd.yyyy. From this I observed that DateSeparator remains which is specified but format of the date changes as soon as the DatePicker loses its focus.

Answer (score 1):

```
DatePicker1.SelectedDate = DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Does this even compile?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the date time format is stored in a resource file, because this would help in internationalization of the app.

You can pick up the format from the resource file and use a `ToString(DATE_FORMAT)`

In your case you might want to use

```
dateTimePicker.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, changing environment to change `DatePicker` format (like `Thread.CurrentCulture`) is not a good idea.
Sure, you can create `Control` derived from `DatePicker` and implement dependency property like `Format`, but this costs too much effort.

Simple and elegant solution I found is binding value not to `SelectedDate` itself, but to some unused property (I used `ToolTip` property for this) and update this property when SelectedDate is changed.

C# implementation for one-way binding looks like this:

```
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.SetBinding(ToolTipProperty, "Date");
    datePicker.SelectedDateChanged += (s, ea) =>
        {
            DateTime? date = datePicker.SelectedDate;
            string value = date != null ? date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null;
            datePicker.ToolTip = value;
        };
```

XAML+C# should look like this:

XAML:

```
<DatePicker ToolTip="{Binding Date Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged"/>
```

C#:

```
private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)sender;
    DateTime? date = datePicker.SelectedDate;
    string value = date != null ? date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null;
    datePicker.ToolTip = value;
}
```

For two-way implementation handle `ToolTipChanged` event the same way to update `SelectedDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      DateLabel.Content = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
```