# DateTime Value to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey, 
This is kind of tough to explain because i don't even know how it is happening. 
I have a datepicker box which when the page is loaded that date box is set to null. Once the user chooses a date and clicks the submit button - the page is reloading and working as it should fine but a time format of zeros appears with the date like so :

5/11/2011 00:00:00

Is there a way i can get rid of the zeros in my post or get methods or any way possible?

Here is how my code looks like in the aspx page:

```
Begin Date: <%:Html.EditorFor(b => b.BeginDate)%><%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.BeginDate)%>

End Date: <%:Html.EditorFor(e => e.EndDate)%><%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.EndDate)%>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }

public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

**This is based off of Darin's Answer:**

in the ViewModel:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString ="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

And in my .aspx page :

```
Begin Date: <%:Html.EditorFor(b => b.BeginDate)%><%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.BeginDate)%>

End Date: <%:Html.EditorFor(e => e.EndDate)%><%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.EndDate)%>
```

Comment: check this out; it is in WPF though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819832/changing-the-string-format-of-the-wpf-datepicker

Comment: in my viewModel this is how my dates are displayed:

public DateTime? BeginDate{get;set;}
public DateTime? EndDate{get; set;}

my html markup is: 
Begin Date: <%:Html.EditorFor(b => b.BeginDate)%><%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.BeginDate)%>
                End Date: <%:Html.EditorFor(e => e.EndDate)%><%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.EndDate)%>

Comment: @Splendor - thanks for the link i will try it out and see if i could apply it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to control it in my report file. in my .rdlc file i created an expression in the box i will show my date to the following:

```
DateValue(Parameters!BeginDate.Value)
```

and that eliminated the zeros from appearing in my text box as well.

thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DisplayFormat` attribute on your view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and in your view you would generate the corresponding input field using the `EditorFor` helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)
```

Now you could attach a datepicker to the resulting input using the same format and when the form is submitted it will keep the same format for the date field.

Comment: can i still keep my datetime values null-able? like 

DateTime? Date{get;set}

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for some reason i am still getting the zeros to show after i click the submit button :( I am not sure what the cause could be. I have the date so that i could be null and as it in as parameters in different places as null could that affect it in any way? Thanks again

Comment: @Amina, after updating your question and showing how the view model look like I can't see the `BeginDate` and `EndDate` properties decorated with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute as in my answer.

Comment: Sorry i posted the original what i started with - i will go ahead and post edit adding the attributes from your answer :)