# How to display Date as MMM-DD dateFormat in WPF DatePicker

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I have WPF DatePicker In My UserControl and I want to display date as MMM-DD format.
I am using MVVM Pattern.
Any One faced this issue.

Comment: Any particular DatePicker control? What have you tried already?

Comment: it is  system.Windows.controls.datePicker Control No third party control used

Answer (score 0):

There us a lot of topic about that whit more or less hacking of the control but may be you could try the DateTimePicker from the WPF Toolkit which has 2 properties 'Format' and 'FormatString'
Like it's describe in this [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17223996).

Set Format=Custom
And FormatString="youre custom format" like "dd::MMM::yyyy hh-mm-ss" or what ever you need