# Datepicker Output Format Datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I try to get a simple Format like this "01.01.1999" - but allways, after end Edit the result (visual and real) value is "01/01/1999 12:00:00 AM") It looks like, that the "StringFormat='dd MM yyyy'" is ignored. How can i fix this?

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="von">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding=von, StringFormat='dd MM yyyy'}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
                                <DatePicker  SelectedDate="{Binding von, StringFormat='dd MM yyyy'}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Solution was very easy:

i changed my "von" from "String" to "DateTime"

```
public DateTime von { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

finally this worked for me:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="von">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding von, StringFormat='dd MM yyyy'}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
                                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding von}"/>

                            </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?:

```
<DatePicker  SelectedDate="{Binding von}">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd MM yyyy', 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

...or any of the other suggestions from here?:

[Changing the string format of the WPF DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819832/changing-the-string-format-of-the-wpf-datepicker)

Comment: Thank you, i tried it before .. same - By using "SelectedDateFormat" i can set the format with "StringFormat='dd MMM yyyy'" but it is only shown in Edit mode