# binding WPF DatePicker to string property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I want to bind `DatePicker` to string property of viewmodel. Trouble is to set proper string format. It's problem-specific to store date in string property.

Binding works fine except string format. My xaml is:

```xml
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Value, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}"/>
```

I expect of string `15.08.2019`, but string is `8/15/2019 12:00:00 AM`

**[Edit]** This question is not duplicate. Changing string format of DatePicker's TextBox by style only affects itself, not binding.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819832/changing-the-string-format-of-the-wpf-datepicker

Comment: Changing string format of DatePicker's TextBox by style only affects itself, not binding.

Comment: It's probably a better idea to change the ViewModel so that it Outputs a ´´´DateTime´´´ property. You could parse the string you already have through ´´´DateTime.Parse´´´

Comment: It's not possible. One row is `ExpandoObject` with custom oblects, depending on the type of "column" (`Enum`) `DataTemplateSelector` returns appropriate editor for cell... All data stored in `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Change the Template of DatePickerTextBox

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path = Value, StringFormat = {}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}}">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat = {}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: This xaml changes string format in DatePiker's editor, but not applies to viewmodel's property. I already tried this solution and it doesn't work for me.