# Using standard WPF DatePicker: How to start with years?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, datepicker

I wish the dropdown to show me years instead of the date of today at the start.
Remark: [Standard WPF DatePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) has no "DisplayMode" as shown in other sources.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798513/wpf-toolkit-datepicker-month-year-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers but I found a solution which I am more content with (using just the standart control)

```
<DatePicker x:Name="_DatePicker" CalendarOpened="_DatePicker_CalendarOpened" />

 private void _DatePicker_CalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // Finding the calendar that is child of stadart WPF DatePicker
        DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker)sender;
        Popup popup = (Popup)datepicker.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", datepicker);
        System.Windows.Controls.Calendar cal = (System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)popup.Child;
        cal.DisplayMode = System.Windows.Controls.CalendarMode.Decade;
    }
```

Good Day and Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;    
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "YYYY dd, mmmm - dddd";
```

OR:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;    
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "YYYY mm, dddd - dddd";
```

For a more expanded explanation, you can click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx).

Comment: The Format and CustomFormat only exists in Windows Forms. WPF has no equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WPF toolkit then

```
<toolkit:Calendar x:Name="yearCalender" DisplayModeChanged="yearCalender_DisplayModeChanged" DisplayMode="Year" />
```

C# code:

```
private void yearCalender_DisplayModeChanged(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
{       
    yearCalender.DisplayMode = Microsoft.Windows.Controls.CalendarMode.Year;
}
```