# XAML pick only month and year in datepicker

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker

I need a DatePicker that can only show month and year as the available choice.

I found that it is possible to go one up when i'm in the choose section.
Is there a possible solution to lock the DatePicker at that?

Comment: please refer to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798513/wpf-toolkit-datepicker-month-year-only It does use the wpf toolkit.

Comment: Can always just remove that portion of the control's template so it's never available to the user.