# WPF DatePicker display and selection

Tags: wpf

My requirement is that, that to display only month and year in datepicker i displayed it but when i click on month its going to date selection how to disable date selection and restrict datepicker to select only month and year

Thank You

Comment: Its surprisingly harder than you would expect, a nasty piece of code/xaml to be done... did it in one of my projects, gonna look for it.

Comment: Are you looking for the calendar part or also for the date format in the `DatePickerTextBox`, where the selected date is displayed and users can manually enter values?

Comment: Hello @grek40 | Thank You for the consideration and reply. I am just looking for the calendar part. Like if user click on `Month` so it didn't go further to the `Date` but the I have Month selected. Thank You for your time.

Comment: If I were you, I would have written one my self. Don't look for any existing ones since it's hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12993391/5265292

**Modifying the popup**

What needs to be done:

- Mark the `DatePicker` control for month/year mode - AttachedProperty will be used
- Register to `DatePicker.CalendarOpened` and `DatePicker.CalendarClosed` events
- Prevent the `Calendar` from entering `CalendarMode.Month`
- Handle `Calendar.SelectedDate` and `Calendar.DisplayDate` - due to the incomplete selection, `SelectedDate` is not reliable by itself.

The following code is maybe not 100% fixed on your issue since I had some different requirements to consider when I wrote it.

```
public static class DatePickerCalendar
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMonthYearProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMonthYear", typeof(bool), typeof(DatePickerCalendar),
                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsMonthYearChanged));

    public static bool GetIsMonthYear(DependencyObject dobj)
    {
        return (bool)dobj.GetValue(IsMonthYearProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsMonthYear(DependencyObject dobj, bool value)
    {
        dobj.SetValue(IsMonthYearProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsMonthYearChanged(DependencyObject dobj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var datePicker = (DatePicker)dobj;

        Application.Current.Dispatcher
            .BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
                         new Action<DatePicker, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs>(SetCalendarEventHandlers),
                         datePicker, e);
    }

    private static void SetCalendarEventHandlers(DatePicker datePicker, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            datePicker.CalendarOpened += DatePickerOnCalendarOpened;
            datePicker.CalendarClosed += DatePickerOnCalendarClosed;
        }
        else
        {
            datePicker.CalendarOpened -= DatePickerOnCalendarOpened;
            datePicker.CalendarClosed -= DatePickerOnCalendarClosed;
        }
    }

    private static void DatePickerOnCalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var calendar = GetDatePickerCalendar(sender);
        calendar.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;

        calendar.DisplayModeChanged += CalendarOnDisplayModeChanged;

        calendar.KeyDown += Calendar_KeyDown;
    }

    private static void DatePickerOnCalendarClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var datePicker = (DatePicker)sender;
        var calendar = GetDatePickerCalendar(sender);
        if (calendar.SelectedDate.HasValue)
        {
            // warning, this might not be what you want, it's a pretty aggressive selection, where the selected date is changed even when keyboard navigating to a new date and then trying to cancel the selection
            calendar.SelectedDate = GetSelectedCalendarDate(calendar.DisplayDate);
        }
        datePicker.SelectedDate = calendar.SelectedDate;

        calendar.DisplayModeChanged -= CalendarOnDisplayModeChanged;

        calendar.KeyDown -= Calendar_KeyDown;
    }

    private static void Calendar_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            var c = (Calendar)sender;
            c.SelectedDate = GetSelectedCalendarDate(c.DisplayDate);
        }
    }

    private static void CalendarOnDisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var calendar = (Calendar)sender;
        if (calendar.DisplayMode != CalendarMode.Month)
            return;

        calendar.SelectedDate = GetSelectedCalendarDate(calendar.DisplayDate);

        var datePicker = GetCalendarsDatePicker(calendar);
        datePicker.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }

    private static Calendar GetDatePickerCalendar(object sender)
    {
        var datePicker = (DatePicker)sender;
        var popup = (Popup)datePicker.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", datePicker);
        return ((Calendar)popup.Child);
    }

    private static DatePicker GetCalendarsDatePicker(FrameworkElement child)
    {
        var parent = (FrameworkElement)child.Parent;
        if (parent.Name == "PART_Root")
            return (DatePicker)parent.TemplatedParent;
        return GetCalendarsDatePicker(parent);
    }

    private static DateTime? GetSelectedCalendarDate(DateTime? selectedDate)
    {
        if (!selectedDate.HasValue)
            return null;
        return new DateTime(selectedDate.Value.Year, selectedDate.Value.Month, 1);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<DatePicker local:DatePickerCalendar.IsMonthYear="True"/>
```

Feel free to ask if something is not clear about any part of the code, i can elaborate on it then.

Answer (score 2):

I implent same code as [@grek40](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41691445/5737774)

Just pasting the code if someone is looking for it.

**XMAL Code**

```
 <DatePicker local:DatePickerCalendar.IsMonthYear="True" 
            local:DatePickerDateFormat.DateFormat="MMM-yyyy"
            Text="MMM-yyyy"></DatePicker>
```

**CS Code**

```
public class DatePickerCalendar
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMonthYearProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMonthYear", typeof(bool), typeof(DatePickerCalendar),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(OnIsMonthYearChanged));

        public static bool GetIsMonthYear(DependencyObject dobj)
        {
            return (bool)dobj.GetValue(IsMonthYearProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsMonthYear(DependencyObject dobj, bool value)
        {
            dobj.SetValue(IsMonthYearProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnIsMonthYearChanged(DependencyObject dobj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var datePicker = (DatePicker)dobj;

            Application.Current.Dispatcher
                .BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
                             new Action<DatePicker, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs>(SetCalendarEventHandlers),
                             datePicker, e);
        }

        private static void SetCalendarEventHandlers(DatePicker datePicker, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
                return;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                datePicker.CalendarOpened += DatePickerOnCalendarOpened;
                datePicker.CalendarClosed += DatePickerOnCalendarClosed;
            }
            else
            {
                datePicker.CalendarOpened -= DatePickerOnCalendarOpened;
                datePicker.CalendarClosed -= DatePickerOnCalendarClosed;
            }
        }

        private static void DatePickerOnCalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            var calendar = GetDatePickerCalendar(sender);
            calendar.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;

            calendar.DisplayModeChanged += CalendarOnDisplayModeChanged;
        }

        private static void DatePickerOnCalendarClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            var datePicker = (DatePicker)sender;
            var calendar = GetDatePickerCalendar(sender);
            datePicker.SelectedDate = calendar.SelectedDate;

            calendar.DisplayModeChanged -= CalendarOnDisplayModeChanged;
        }

        private static void CalendarOnDisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var calendar = (System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)sender;
            if (calendar.DisplayMode != CalendarMode.Month)
                return;

            calendar.SelectedDate = GetSelectedCalendarDate(calendar.DisplayDate);

            var datePicker = GetCalendarsDatePicker(calendar);
            datePicker.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }

        private static System.Windows.Controls.Calendar GetDatePickerCalendar(object sender)
        {
            var datePicker = (DatePicker)sender;
            var popup = (Popup)datePicker.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", datePicker);
            return ((System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)popup.Child);
        }

        private static DatePicker GetCalendarsDatePicker(FrameworkElement child)
        {
            var parent = (FrameworkElement)child.Parent;
            if (parent.Name == "PART_Root")
                return (DatePicker)parent.TemplatedParent;
            return GetCalendarsDatePicker(parent);
        }

        private static DateTime? GetSelectedCalendarDate(DateTime? selectedDate)
        {
            if (!selectedDate.HasValue)
                return null;
            return new DateTime(selectedDate.Value.Year, selectedDate.Value.Month, 1);
        }
    }

    public class DatePickerDateFormat
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DateFormatProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DateFormat", typeof(string), typeof(DatePickerDateFormat),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(OnDateFormatChanged));

        public static string GetDateFormat(DependencyObject dobj)
        {
            return (string)dobj.GetValue(DateFormatProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDateFormat(DependencyObject dobj, string value)
        {
            dobj.SetValue(DateFormatProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnDateFormatChanged(DependencyObject dobj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var datePicker = (DatePicker)dobj;

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action<DatePicker>(ApplyDateFormat), datePicker);
        }
        private static void ApplyDateFormat(DatePicker datePicker)
        {
            var binding = new Binding("SelectedDate")
            {
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource { AncestorType = typeof(DatePicker) },
                Converter = new DatePickerDateTimeConverter(),
                ConverterParameter = new Tuple<DatePicker, string>(datePicker, GetDateFormat(datePicker)),
                StringFormat = GetDateFormat(datePicker) // This is also new but didnt seem to help
            };

            var textBox = GetTemplateTextBox(datePicker);
            textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

            textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown;
            textBox.PreviewKeyDown += TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown;

            var dropDownButton = GetTemplateButton(datePicker);

            datePicker.CalendarOpened -= DatePickerOnCalendarOpened;
            datePicker.CalendarOpened += DatePickerOnCalendarOpened;

            // Handle Dropdownbutton PreviewMouseUp to prevent issue of flickering textboxes
            dropDownButton.PreviewMouseUp -= DropDownButtonPreviewMouseUp;
            dropDownButton.PreviewMouseUp += DropDownButtonPreviewMouseUp;
        }

        private static ButtonBase GetTemplateButton(DatePicker datePicker)
        {
            return (ButtonBase)datePicker.Template.FindName("PART_Button", datePicker);
        }


        /// <summary>
        ///     Prevents a bug in the DatePicker, where clicking the Dropdown open button results in Text being set to default formatting regardless of StringFormat or binding overrides
        /// </summary>
        private static void DropDownButtonPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe == null) return;

            var datePicker = fe.TryFindParent<DatePicker>();
            if (datePicker == null || datePicker.SelectedDate == null) return;

            var dropDownButton = GetTemplateButton(datePicker);

            // Dropdown button was clicked
            if (e.OriginalSource == dropDownButton && datePicker.IsDropDownOpen == false)
            {
                // Open dropdown
                datePicker.SetCurrentValue(DatePicker.IsDropDownOpenProperty, true);

                // Mimic everything else in the standard DatePicker dropdown opening *except* setting textbox value 
                datePicker.SetCurrentValue(DatePicker.DisplayDateProperty, datePicker.SelectedDate.Value);

                // Important otherwise calendar does not work
                dropDownButton.ReleaseMouseCapture();

                // Prevent datePicker.cs from handling this event 
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }



        private static TextBox GetTemplateTextBox(Control control)
        {
            control.ApplyTemplate();
            return (TextBox)control?.Template?.FindName("PART_TextBox", control);
        }

        private static void TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key != Key.Return)
                return;

            /* DatePicker subscribes to its TextBox's KeyDown event to set its SelectedDate if Key.Return was
             * pressed. When this happens its text will be the result of its internal date parsing until it
             * loses focus or another date is selected. A workaround is to stop the KeyDown event bubbling up
             * and handling setting the DatePicker.SelectedDate. */

            e.Handled = true;

            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            var datePicker = (DatePicker)textBox.TemplatedParent;
            var dateStr = textBox.Text;
            var formatStr = GetDateFormat(datePicker);
            datePicker.SelectedDate = DatePickerDateTimeConverter.StringToDateTime(datePicker, formatStr, dateStr);
        }

        private static void DatePickerOnCalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /* When DatePicker's TextBox is not focused and its Calendar is opened by clicking its calendar button
             * its text will be the result of its internal date parsing until its TextBox is focused and another
             * date is selected. A workaround is to set this string when it is opened. */

            var datePicker = (DatePicker)sender;
            var textBox = GetTemplateTextBox(datePicker);
            var formatStr = GetDateFormat(datePicker);
            textBox.Text = DatePickerDateTimeConverter.DateTimeToString(formatStr, datePicker.SelectedDate);
        }

        private class DatePickerDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var formatStr = ((Tuple<DatePicker, string>)parameter).Item2;
                var selectedDate = (DateTime?)value;
                return DateTimeToString(formatStr, selectedDate);
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var tupleParam = ((Tuple<DatePicker, string>)parameter);
                var dateStr = (string)value;
                return StringToDateTime(tupleParam.Item1, tupleParam.Item2, dateStr);
            }

            public static string DateTimeToString(string formatStr, DateTime? selectedDate)
            {
                return selectedDate.HasValue ? selectedDate.Value.ToString(formatStr) : null;
            }

            public static DateTime? StringToDateTime(DatePicker datePicker, string formatStr, string dateStr)
            {
                DateTime date;
                var canParse = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, formatStr, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                      DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

                if (!canParse)
                    canParse = DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

                return canParse ? date : datePicker.SelectedDate;
            }


        }

    }



public static class FEExten
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a parent of a given item on the visual tree.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="child">A direct or indirect child of the
    /// queried item.</param>
    /// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted
    /// type parameter. If not matching item can be found, a null
    /// reference is being returned.</returns>
    public static T TryFindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        //get parent item
        DependencyObject parentObject = GetParentObject(child);

        //we've reached the end of the tree
        if (parentObject == null) return null;

        //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
        T parent = parentObject as T;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            return parent;
        }
        else
        {
            //use recursion to proceed with next level
            return TryFindParent<T>(parentObject);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is an alternative to WPF's
    /// <see cref="VisualTreeHelper.GetParent"/> method, which also
    /// supports content elements. Keep in mind that for content element,
    /// this method falls back to the logical tree of the element!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="child">The item to be processed.</param>
    /// <returns>The submitted item's parent, if available. Otherwise
    /// null.</returns>
    public static DependencyObject GetParentObject(this DependencyObject child)
    {
        if (child == null) return null;

        //handle content elements separately
        ContentElement contentElement = child as ContentElement;
        if (contentElement != null)
        {
            DependencyObject parent = ContentOperations.GetParent(contentElement);
            if (parent != null) return parent;

            FrameworkContentElement fce = contentElement as FrameworkContentElement;
            return fce != null ? fce.Parent : null;
        }

        //also try searching for parent in framework elements (such as DockPanel, etc)
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
        if (frameworkElement != null)
        {
            DependencyObject parent = frameworkElement.Parent;
            if (parent != null) return parent;
        }

        //if it's not a ContentElement/FrameworkElement, rely on VisualTreeHelper
        return VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
}
```

**PS**: 
Help is taken from this [GitHub Project](https://gist.github.com/crclayton/5aa7de782cfca6b59e616331af31c42c).

Credit goes to the original author: [@crclayton](https://github.com/crclayton)