# datetime converter WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have this converter that i made to get the current time once the date is selected from the DataPicker. In string Date i am getting the value that was selected from the DatePicker, but i cant seem to only get the date. The format that is coming into the Value property is 9/24/2013 12:00:00 I would like it to be 9/24/2013

the error i am getting is "Error    122 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument"

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
            string date = value.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
            return (date);
            }

             return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't get this error message somewhere else? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx Or are you using .Net Framework 1.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast it to DateTime first:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is DateTime)
    {
        DateTime test = (DateTime) value;
        string date = test.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
        return date;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: But the if-condition will be satisfied ONLY if its DateTime

Why should it be typecasted?

Comment: @NithinNayagam It can be an object type that derives from DateTime.

Comment: when i try this i get 'Specified cast is not valid'

Answer (score 1):

You should cast value to `DateTime` type, because there is not a `ToString(String f)` method for the type of `Object`.

```
if (value is DateTime)
{
   var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
   return dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}

return string.Empty;
```

Comment: This won't compile, since DateTime is a value type and cannot be cast with the as keyword.

Answer (score 0):

After check on type of value you need cast it to appropriate type, to be able to perform "ToString" call with format parameter. Try:

```
if (value is DateTime)
{
    var dateValue = value as DateTime;
    string date = dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    return date; 
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `is` operator. it will be very slowly coz. it equivalent to two-times casting in your case.

Comment: Actually yes, but i wrote answer that fits to author's convert function. In addition it is not good practice to write functions that accept 'object' as parameter and returns also object.

Comment: this is implementation of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Converter on a WPF DatePicker control, you should note that the WPF DatePicker will itself reformat the date *despite the converter that you use*. You will have to [style the Datepicker to include a StringFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641577/how-to-change-format-e-g-dd-mmm-yyyy-of-datetimepicker-in-wpf-application/4404199#4404199).

There is a related question here: how to [show just Month Year string format in a DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798513/wpf-toolkit-datepicker-month-year-only) which shows an attached property to modify the behaviour of DatePicker to display a custom format. This is needed because of a deficiency in the WPF Datepicker control itself.

Also note there are some caveats, notably the DatePicker will flicker between its default stringformat and the one you apply! I answered in the above question [a workaround for to apply a custom Format to WPF Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971983/303612) without the flicker.

Hope you find the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is DateTime)
    {
        string date=value.Date.ToShortDateString();
        return (date);
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```