DateTimePicker: how can I remove the "time" section?
I've a generic DateTimePicker control in MahApps:
<controls:DateTimePicker x:Name="CreationDate"
                         SelectedDateTime="{Binding CreationDate}"
                         Width="170"
                         Height="40"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Culture="en-US"
                         Focusable="False"
                         controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Creation Date"
                         controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
                         SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                         SelectedTimeFormat="Short" />

But I'm not able to hide the Time (both on textbox, and on the popup opened when I click the icon.
How can I remove it?

Changing the format? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641577/how-to-change-format-e-g-dd-mmm-yyyy-of-datetimepicker-in-wpf-application

@flackoverstow already did with SelectedDateFormat="Short", as you can see. but doesn't works.

@shingo don't think there is DatePicker on MahApps? https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/DateTimePicker

I mean DatePicker of WPF.

yes, but I'm using MahApps.Metro for styling and stuff (as for tag in the question).

Have you added theme settings to the app.xaml? The style of the DatePicker should look the same as other MahApps.Metro's controls.

Native DatePicker have no elements as Metro, such watermaker and other stuff

With luck, MahApps.Metro should add a lot of custom properties such as TextBoxHelper.Watermark to the native controls.

Yes, thats why I want to use Metro, which hasn't DatePicker :)

I think I need to add some screenshots to show why I said you should just use the DatePicker of WPF.
Here's what I got, a window with a DatePicker, a TimePicker and a DateTimePicker:

You can see that the styles of DatePicker and DateTimePicker are consistent, and you can customize the watermark.
Here's the style after you click the icon:
 
And the code:
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="137" Width="212">
    <Grid>
        <mah:DateTimePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="140"
                            mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Pick" />
        <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="10,41,0,0" Width="140"
                    mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Pick" />
        <mah:TimePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="10,72,0,0" Width="140"
                        mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Pick" />
    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>


Wow, that's pretty nice! Didn't know it could "attach" new elements to common object. Nice, thanks! A tip request: is it possible with DatePicker to open the popup clicking on the textbox? So for both icon and textbox?

I think a simple way is to create a user control with a DatePicker and a transparent button over it, and use the button to toggle the popup calendar.

This control doesn't support it. But you can create custom control out of it and override GetValueForTextBox method as below
public class CustomDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    protected override string GetValueForTextBox()
    {
        return SelectedDateTime?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
}

In XAML
<local:CustomDateTimePicker />

Make sure you can local namespace defined in XAML
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApplication"

UPDATE:
Here is the modified code to remove the time selector.

Download the DateTimePicker.xaml file from https://gist.github.com/Cinchoo/a877788069911bb6ee82e3f2e619884b. Defines the modified datetime picker with CustomDateTimePickerTemplate1 key.

In your control file, reference the resource in resource dictionary

Reference the template CustomDateTimePickerTemplate1 in the datetime control


Here the sample
<Window
    x:Class="WPFSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Converters;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFSample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="DateTimePicker.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <local:CustomDateTimePicker
            x:Name="CreationDate"
            Width="170"
            Height="40"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
            controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Creation Date"
            Culture="en-US"
            Focusable="False"
            IsClockVisible="False"
            PickerVisibility="Second"
            SelectedDateFormat="Short"
            SelectedDateTime="{Binding CreationDate}"
            SelectedTimeFormat="Short"
            Template="{DynamicResource CustomDateTimePickerTemplate1}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

Referenced Nuget packages


but how can I hide also the time selector on the popup?

I'm afraid they have properties to turn off time selector completely. They provided PickerVisibility to customize it. But doesn't allow to hide complete time picker component. May be overriding their template is the way to go.

Is there any starting point on doing this?

download their source from https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro. take the datetimepicker template as base, override it by using style / template. there are plenty of samples there how to customize control using templates.

I'll try and let you know, thanks man!

do you mean this? https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Themes/DateTimePicker.xaml

Yes, that's the one.

see update above for custom template and use of it in control.

I think shingo put an easy answer to this! Thanks for the huge effort anyway :)
